# Convert Bigquery SQL to a Materialized View

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have this bigquery sql command which gets data from DB in a certain format. I want it in materialized view but i am getting following error

```
Incremental materialized views may not use the ARRAY function.
```

Here is the SELECT SQL COMMAND

```
SELECT
  '' as Status,
  Country,
  'US-Docketing' as Source,
  customer_name as CustomerName,
  customer_number as CustomerNumber,
  client_number as ClientName,
  ClientId,
  application_number as `ApplicationNo`,
  docket_queue_id as `DocketNo`,
  attorney_docket_number as `AttorneyDocketNo`,
  DateReceived as `ReceivedDate`,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(
      document_details_unnest.DocumentCode,
      document_details_unnest.Title,
      document_details_unnest.JobDocumentId,
      document_details_unnest.JobDocumentSourceId,
      ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
               annotationaId,
               display_name,
               Value,
               source
             FROM UNNEST(document_details_unnest.annotations)) as annotations
          )
  ) as DocumentDetails
FROM `PROJECT.POC.sample_mat_view`, UNNEST(document_details) as document_details_unnest
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11;
```

I tried non incremental version of materialized view as well but it's minimumm staleness can be 30 mins. And i couldn't seem to REFRESH it manually.

If there's no way to create incremental materializd view, How can i change SQL command to give me same schema without using ARRAY function.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incremental materialized view has some limitation and you reached one. Non incremental version is more expensive but solve those limitation. The latest alternative is to change your model and the data exposed to be compliant with incremental materialized view. Nothing magic here.

Comment: Hi, As commented by @guillaume blaquiere Incremental materialized view has some limitations and you reached one.

Non incremental version is more expensive but solve those limitation. The latest alternative is to change your model and the data exposed to be compliant with incremental materialized view. Please refer to the [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#:%7E:text=Materialized%20views%20are%20precomputed%20in,Materialized%20views%20return%20fresh%20data.) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create) for more description.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere and Sushma. We were using the Mat View for optimisation purposes because it was supposed to be used in an API. But now the backend table itself has been optimised so we are returning data from itself only, so the Mat View approach is not being used anymore. Just wanted to let you guys know. Later!